# Equivalence between the category $\text{Ho}(\mathcal{M})$ and $\text{Ho}(\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{F}})$

Tags: category-theory, homotopy-theory, model-categories

Let $(\mathcal{M}, \mathcal{W}, \mathcal{C},\mathcal{F})$ be a model category and $\text{Ho}(\mathcal{M})$ its homotopy category. Now we consider $ \mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{F}}$ the full subcategory of fibrant object. Now, I want to show that we have an equivalence between $\text{Ho}(\mathcal{M})$ and $\text{Ho}(\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{F}})$.

For that I first construct a functor:
$$\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{F}} \xrightarrow{\subset} \mathcal{M}\xrightarrow{\lambda}\text{Ho}(\mathcal{M})$$
Where $\lambda$ is the localization functor. Then since by definition, this functor sends weak equivalences to isomorphism, we get a functor $\text{Ho}(\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{F}})\to \text{Ho}(\mathcal{M})$.

Now I want to construct a functor $text{Ho}(\mathcal{M}\to \text{Ho}(\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{F}}))$:
For that I start to construct the following functor:
$$R: \mathcal{M}\rightarrow \mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{F}} $$
We define $R$ on object: We take $X\in \text{Ob}(\mathcal{M})$, and consider the unique morphism $X\to *$, where $*$ is the final object of $\mathcal{M}$, by the factorization axiom we get :
$$X\overset{\sim}{\hookrightarrow}R(X) \twoheadrightarrow *$$
We take $R(X)$ to be the object in the middle.
Now I want to define $R$ on morphism, and in my definition of a model category, I didn't add the fact that this decomposition should be functorial, so if I consider a morphism $f:X\rightarrow Y$ in $\mathcal{M}$ I don't know how to construct a morphism $R(f): R(X)\rightarrow R(Y)$ such that $R$ is indeed a functor. Any hints on what I should use to construct such a morphism? And more importantly am I on the right track to prove my point ?

Comment: It's easier to show that the functor you have already constructed is fully faithful and essentially surjective on objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a substantial difference in complexity between showing full and faithfulness and showing an inverse functor exists.

Note that a morphism $f:X\rightarrow Y$ gives rise to a commutative square of the form
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
  X & \overset{f}{\longrightarrow} Y  \longrightarrow & RY\\
  \downarrow^\text{triv}_\text{cofib} &&\downarrow_\text{fib}\\
  RX &-\!-\!-\!-\!\longrightarrow&\ast
\end{array}$$
so you get a lift $RX \rightarrow RY$. If you show that this lift is unique up to homotopy, you can use that either to define the inverse functor on morphisms, or deduce from it that the inclusion is faithful (it is obviously essentially surjective and full).

Comment: One major difference in complexity is that defining an inverse functor requires using the axiom of choice (possibly on a proper class, so "global choice") to pick the $R(X)$, whereas showing it's fully faithful & essentially surjective doesn't require this

Comment: The axiom of choice seems to be essential for a fully faithful essentially surjective functor to be an equivalence of categories. This is because we have to choose for each object of the target category two things: a preimage in the domain category, and an isomorphism for the counit of the adjunction on this object.

Comment: @BrendanMurphy I don't get your point. If you don't believe in the large axiom of choice, you don't prove the equivalence OP asked for by proving esssurj+full+faithf. If you do believe in it, both methods have the same complexity.

Comment: If you don't believe the large axiom of choice, the definition of an equivalence of categories o is taken to be fully faithful+essentially surjective rather than having a quasi inverse